# CSS translateY stuttering for sections larger than 100vh

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a "slide-up fade-out" transition using CSS & Javascript as an alternate for pagepiling library. The code works fine when the sections are limited to 100vh. But if any section is more than 100vh in height and if it is scrolled to the bottom, the translateY transition stutter.

I understand this is happening because section height relative to the body changes and the scrollbar reduces and the content adjusts back to the bottom which causes the stutter. But I'm hoping I'm overlooking something here.

```js
$('body')
.on('mousewheel',async function(e){
    if( transitioning ) return false
    let cS = $('section.active'),
        nS = $(cS).next('section'),
        pS = $(cS).prev('section');
    
    if( e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0 && nS.length && ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) ){
        setScrollLevel(1);
        transitioning = true;
        $('body').css({ 'overflow-y':'hidden' });
        await new Promise( r => setTimeout(r,100) );
        $(cS).css({ 'transform': 'translateY(-100%)' });
        await new Promise( r => setTimeout(r,750) );
        $(cS).removeClass('active');
        $(nS).addClass('active');
        $('body').css({ 'overflow-y':'' })
        transitioning = false;
    }
    if( e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0 && pS.length && $(window).scrollTop() <= 0 ){
        setScrollLevel(-1);
        transitioning = true;
        $('body').css({ 'overflow-y':'hidden' })
        $(cS).removeClass('active');
        $(pS).addClass('active');
        await new Promise( r => setTimeout(r,100) );
        $(pS).css({ 'transform':'translateY(0)' });
        await new Promise( r => setTimeout(r,750) );
        $('body').css({ 'overflow-y':'' })
        transitioning = false;
    }
})
```

```css
section{
    position: absolute;
    contain: content;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: none;
    transition: transform ease-in-out .75s,
                opacity ease-in-out .75s;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    display: flex;
    opacity: 0
}
section.active{
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
}
section > *:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 4vh;
}
section > *:first-of-type {
    margin-top: 8vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[This site](http://paul-themes.com/html/gilber/#Education) is what I'm trying to replicate.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the only way to make it work is by keeping the height of the section constant. So instead of making changes in height/scroll to the `section` element, I added a ````div``` inside that changes in height keeping the section height the same.

Before the structure was

```
<section> <!-- the height of this changed when Y-tranform occured -->
  <div class="container">
     <div class="content">
     </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

The current structure

```
<section>
  <div class="content-holder"> <!-- Y-tranform occurs here -->
     <div class="container">
       <div class="content">
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</section>
```